# Issue with accessing environment variable set within a sudo command

Tags: linux, sudo, csh

I have issue with echo'ing an environment variable that is set within a sudo statement.

The following is just a example snippet that is similar to my actual script.  `echo $OS` prints nothing.   I would be greatly appreciate if someone can shed some light into what I did wrong.  Thank you!

```
sudo -s /bin/csh <<EOF
xauth merge /home/`logname`/.Xauthority
setenv OS blah
echo $OS
gvim
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; The variable reference `$OS` in the heredoc needs to be escaped/quoted

The problem is not `sudo` itself, but how the csh script was written.

### Explanation

The running shell/script expands the variable `$OS` inside the [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)
*before* it sends the result to `/bin/csh` in your example.

We can make a little test and make a new environment variable with a value and
confirm that the it gets expanded in the heredoc.

```
setenv OS host
/bin/csh << EOF
setenv OS guest
echo $OS
EOF
```

The output should be `host`

The man page for [csh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/csh.1#Input/output) describes the syntax for heredoc as follow

> ### Input/output
>
> The standard input and the standard output of a command may be redirected
> with the following syntax:
>
> `<< word`
>
> Read the shell input up to a line that is identical to word. ...
> **Unless a quoting ‘\’, ‘"’, ‘'’ or ‘`’ appears in word, variable and
> command substitution is performed on the intervening lines**, allowing ‘\’
> to quote ‘$’, ‘\’ and ‘`’.

### Solution

If we surround the `EOF` with quotes, the variable will not get expanded.

```
setenv OS host
/bin/csh << 'EOF'
setenv OS guest
echo $OS
'EOF'
```

The output should be `guest`.

As an exercise, you could try to substitute `/bin/csh` with `cat` to confirm the heredoc

```
setenv OS host
cat << 'EOF'
setenv OS guest
echo $OS
'EOF'
```

The output would look like this

```
setenv OS guest
echo $OS
```

Now we know that csh that gets executed by sudo will read the script with `$OS`